# connection invalid using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

Well , I try to post data to my server as soon as the app launches with the help of NSURLConnection . Here's my code in swift

```
let requests : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let useragent : String
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
        useragent = "iPhone"
    }
    else {
        useragent = "iPad"
    }

    requests.setValue(useragent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    requests.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    requests.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    let jsonstring : String = String(data: urlData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    NSLog("Data being posted to the server")
    NSLog("Post Data  : Data being posted to server")
    requests.timeoutInterval = 60.0
    requests.HTTPBody = jsonstring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    requests.setValue("\(jsonstring.characters.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    let conn : NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: requests, delegate: self)!
    conn.isProxy()
```

I tried printing things in the device logs and the url and the data to be posted (dictionary named json) are all perfect . The logs print these lines successfully as well

```
NSLog("Data being posted to the server")
    NSLog("Post Data  : Data being posted to server")
```

But after this , the app crashes and I could see "Connection invalid " in the device logs . Can anyone help in letting me know if I'm wrong at any point here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use "Postman" App to check the error

Comment: Where in your code does the application crash?  What type of crash are you seeing?  Are any messages are printed to the console at the time the crash occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly where the problem is, as the code seems alright, but I'd suggest using `NSURLSession` instead, because `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9 and above. Also replace `NSLog(string)` with `print(string)` because `print` is the method you're meant to use in swift for debugging.

Comment: These are the comments in log

Comment: Apr  1 12:05:01 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.manageengine.mdm.ios[0x7a62][2748]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Apr  1 12:05:01 iPad SpringBoard[1643] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Apr  1 12:05:01 iPad SpringBoard[1643] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Apr  1 12:05:01 iPad SpringBoard[1643] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid

Comment: @kabiroberai , Is it necessary for me to use start() if i haven't used start immediately : true while initialising?

Comment: I have checked in postman app and it works fine there .. Should i include conn.start() after initialising connection @PayalManiyar?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma as per the `NSURLConnection` class reference, 
"Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method and provide NO for the startImmediately parameter."
So no, I don't think it is necessary for you to call `start()`. Have you tried the other option I suggested?

Comment: @kabiroberai , NSURLSession ? If i do that , I have to change a lot of methods , So may be i'll do it . but as of now , I want this data posted which is working fine when i check using postman .

Comment: @ManeeshSharma
I think yes you should use start().

Comment: @ManeeshSharma alright. Could you please update your code with the function body of `isProxy`?

Comment: @kabiroberai , I know the methods are deprecated , but it should be working alright as the deployment target for my app is ios 8.0 and above

Comment: did not get u @kabiroberai , isProxy What ?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma `isProxy` doesn't seem to be a built-in method of `NSURLConnection`. Have you created it yourself? If so, could you please update your question with what `isProxy` does?

Comment: @PayalManiyar , Do you see any other possibility for this connection not getting established ?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma I think I may know the error. Could you tell me whether the url uses the protocol `http` or `https`?

Comment: @kabiroberai , it is there built in , it returns a bool value.

Comment: @kabiroberai , its there in this protocol ....public protocol NSObjectProtocol

Comment: @ManeeshSharma
Check whether delegate method is called or not.

Comment: @ManeeshSharma no I meant does the url have an "http://" or "https://"?

Comment: What do u mean by Delagate method is called or not @PayalManiyar

Comment: @kabiroberai https

Comment: @ManeeshSharma huh... If it was `http`, then the error may have been caused by `App Transport Security`, but since it's `https`, I'm not too sure what the issue is

Comment: @kabiroberai , exactly ... I'm all over the place because of this !

Comment: @ManeeshSharma
      NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/

Comment: i have used didReceiveData , But that would be called only when there is a connection established .. I haven't used didFinishLoading. @PayalManiyar

Comment: @ManeeshSharma
Use below method to make connection

Comment: NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: @ManeeshSharma are you by any chance using the `CIContext` class?

Comment: I'm working with swift , not with objective-c @PayalManiyar

Comment: @PayalManiyar's code in Swift would be `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)`

Comment: And , i'm not using     CIContext

Comment: Should I really do that ? Because , response and error havent been declared yet , and moreover , the same code in objective-c is working fine

Comment: NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:requests delegate:self];
    [conn isProxy];

Comment: @ManeeshSharma
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350581/initwithrequestdelegate-is-deprecated-first-deprecated-in-ios-9-0-use-nsu

Comment: @PayalManiyar , The person has clearly mentioned that he's working with ios 9 ., so it's deprecated whereas I have told am working with ios 8 as deployment target.